# How to Display a Pop-up Notification during an Incoming Call on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, caller-id

I want to show the name of a caller during an incoming call. For this, I'm creating a notification. The notification is delivered in the notifications with the name of the person. I want the notification to pop up and display the name.
I've already tried setting IMPORTANCE_HIGH and PRIORITY_HIGH for the Notification channel and the notification respectively.

I'm using onScreenCall() method in CallScreeningService to trigger the notification.

I'm also open to other solutions by which I can show who is calling. I tried starting a new activity but that doesn't work when the app is closed. I'm however able to detect incoming calls despite my app being closed.

PS: I'm not replacing the default incoming call notification. I just want to show an additional notification with the name of the caller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192049/8719734 , have u tried this ?

Comment: What's the Android version you're targeting? For Android 10, this looks like the way to go: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity but I'm not replacing the default incoming call notification. I just want to show an additional notification with the name of the caller.