# Blocking call on android from Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to block call on android device from a Flutter app, getting this error

Accessing hidden method Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getITelephony()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
E/CallBlocker(19807): Error blocking call: android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getITelephony []
`package com.block.appsolute.appsolute_block

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a Native feature some packages are not updated for latest Kotlin code. Try this package
   https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit
   https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming
2. If this doesn't work **create your own plugin** using `ConnectionService` native class which can put hold on calls. This is not easy task you have to check restrictions based on these services on **Android O** and above. Here are some reference links to try

a. [Android ConnectionService incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158693/android-connectionservice-incoming-calls)

b. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService